# File missing/Wrong config. Metro Server for React Native

Tags: react-native

I'm running a react native app in actual physical device using Metro server app is running fine but I'm see this error in logs.

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/home/user/Workspace/mobile/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.company&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
    at Object.openSync (fs.js:498:3)
    at Object.readFileSync (fs.js:394:35)
    at getCodeFrame (/home/user/Workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:919:18)
    at Server._symbolicate (/home/user/Workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:992:22)
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async Server._processRequest (/home/user/Workspace/mobile/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:403:7) {
  errno: -2,
  syscall: 'open',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  path: '/home/user/Workspace/mobile/http:/localhost:8081/index.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&minify=false&app=com.company&modulesOnly=false&runModule=true'
}
```

it seems a path issue but not able to find where to make changes for this

Comment: Please see [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/5211833)